# What does "the must of dried leaves" mean?

Tags: meaning, nouns, vocabulary

Can I say "must" here, means smell?

> . . . the smell of the air that day: piñon burning somewhere in the distance, **the must** of dried leaves, the lingering smoke of a campfire clinging to his wool shirt . . .

<sub>Source: [*Note To Self*](http://vestalreview.net/NoteToSelf.html) written by Tracy Guzeman</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning could be [A] *a musky smell*

**must** [5] n: *musk* [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/must) ...

**musk** [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/musk)
1.

a. A greasy secretion with a powerful odor, produced in a glandular sac in the abdomen of a male musk deer and used in traditional medicines and formerly in the manufacture of perfumes.

b. A similar secretion produced by certain other animals, such as an otter or civet.

c. A synthetic chemical resembling natural musk in odor or use.

2.

a. The odor of musk.

b. An odor similar to musk.

.....................

***or*** [B] *a damp, mouldy smell*

**must** ['2'] n 1. mustiness or mould [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/must)

{Noun   1.  **mustiness** - the quality of smelling or tasting old or stale or mouldy  -  moldiness, must

staleness - having lost purity and freshness as a consequence of aging
[[Based on WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. © 2003-2012 Princeton University, Farlex Inc](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mustiness)]}

Some might not be able to distinguish the nuances.

Answer (score 1):

[Must](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/must#must-3):(n)

> - Mustiness, dampness, or mould.
>
>   - a pervasive smell of must.

(ODO)

- I think it  refers to the smell of damp, wet leaves on the ground.

Comment: the smell of wet leaves coming from dried leaves?!!

Comment: @Jhon Smith -          Dried means dead leaves on the ground, damp probably with  dew or rain.!!

Comment: @JhonSmith if the leaves were bone dry they would probably smell of nothing, but after the morning mist has risen, one can sense a dampness and a mustiness in the air. Besides, this is called *poetic license* in literature.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, you are quite right.